# VB2008 with MySQLConnector .net 6.1

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have the following code:

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports MySql.Data.Types

Public Class FormMain

Private Sub FormMain_Load ...

```
  ' Open Database
  Dim objMySQL As New MySqlConnection
```

End Sub

End Class

I get the compiler error message:
error BC30560: "MySqlConnection" ist im Namespace "MySql.Data.MySqlClient" nicht eindeutig.
in English (I think): "MySqlConnection" is not unique in Namespace "MySql.Data.MySqlClient".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference for the error:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f0k13d2.aspx

Possible answer:

http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2008/12/bc30560-mysqlconnection-is-ambiguous-in.html